# How to count specific row tuples in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have some dataframes, generated with the following code:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import pandas as pd

mydict = { ('x305', 'BoxType1-1'): { 'box': 'x305', 'box#': '0', 'boxCode': 'Z8', 'version': '00.00' },
           ('x305', 'BoxType1-2'): { 'box': 'x305', 'box#': '0', 'boxCode': 'K8', 'version': '01.00' },
           ('x307', 'BoxType1-1'): { 'box': 'x307', 'box#': '0', 'boxCode': 'Z8', 'serialNo': 'None', 'version': '00.00' },
           ('x307', 'BoxType2-1'): { 'box': 'x307', 'box#': '0', 'boxCode': 'Z8', 'serialNo': 'None', 'version': '00.00' }, 
           ('x403', 'BoxType1-1'): { 'box': 'x403', 'box#': '0', 'boxCode': 'Z8', 'bla': 'None', 'version': '00.00' }, 
           ('x405', 'BoxType1-2'): { 'box': 'x405', 'box#': '0', 'boxCode': 'Z8', 'serialNo': 'None', 'version': '00.00' }, 
           ('x405', 'BoxType2-1'): { 'box': 'x405', 'box#': '0', 'boxCode': 'Z8', 'version': '00.00' }, 
           ('x510', 'BoxType1-3'): { 'box': 'x510', 'box#': '0', 'boxCode': 'Z8', 'version': '01.00' } }

boxTypes = [ 'BoxType1', 'BoxType2' ]
dataframes = defaultdict( set )

for boxType in boxTypes:
   dataframes[ boxType ] = pd.DataFrame.from_dict( { ( box, bt ): mydict[ ( box, bt ) ]
                                                     for box, bt in mydict.keys()
                                                     if boxType in bt },
                                                   orient='index' )

print dataframes[ 'BoxType1' ]
                 box   version box# boxCode  bla serialNo
x305 BoxType1-1  x305   00.00    0      Z8   NaN      NaN
     BoxType1-2  x305   01.00    0      K8   NaN      NaN
x307 BoxType1-1  x307   00.00    0      Z8   NaN     None
x403 BoxType1-1  x403   00.00    0      Z8  None      NaN
x405 BoxType1-2  x405   00.00    0      Z8   NaN     None
x510 BoxType1-3  x510   01.00    0      Z8   NaN      NaN
```

Now I am trying to find way to count specific row tuples throughout a dataframe. For example, I want to have a function like this:

```
def countRowTuples( df, columns ):
    '''
    Count occurrences of row tuple in dataframe
    and return a new dataframe with a count column at the end
    '''

df2 = countRowTuples( dataframes['BoxType1'], columns=[ boxCode, bla, version ] )

df2 = 
                 box   version box# boxCode  bla serialNo  count
x305 BoxType1-1  x305   00.00    0      Z8   NaN      NaN    3
     BoxType1-2  x305   01.00    0      K8   NaN      NaN    1
x307 BoxType1-1  x307   00.00    0      Z8   NaN     None    3
x403 BoxType1-1  x403   00.00    0      Z8  None      NaN    1
x405 BoxType1-2  x405   00.00    0      Z8   NaN     None    3
x510 BoxType1-3  x510   01.00    0      Z8   NaN      NaN    1
```

Or, the function could get rid of the original indices and duplicate rows, and return a dataframe like this:

```
df2 = 
    version boxCode  bla   count
1   00.00     Z8     NaN     3
2   01.00     K8     NaN     1
3   00.00     Z8     None    1
4   01.00     Z8     NaN     1
```

Anyone have any good insight how I might go about this?

I have tried the following but keep getting an empty dataframe returned :(.

```
df = dataframes[ 'BoxType1' ]
print df.groupby(df.columns.tolist()).size().reset_index().rename(columns={0:'count'})

Empty DataFrame
Columns: [box, version, box#, boxCode, bla, serialNo, count]
Index: []
```

Comment: Where does the 4 in the first row come from? Whys is it a 4?

Comment: Can you show code to generate your input df?

Comment: @ Scott Boston - I have edited my question  to include code used to generate the dataframe. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The group by is not performing the desired counts due to the null values. Try this:

```
dataframes['BoxType1'].fillna("NaN").groupby(["version", "boxCode", "bla"]).size().reset_index(name="count")
```

Comment: Thank you Seiji Armstrong this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: No worries, I had a similar issue some time ago. 
btw I used `"NaN"` to match your output, but it's in general not good practice to use this `str` as it might be confused with `NaN` null values.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to add another column filled with ones, group by the fields for which you want the distinct values, (you will need to fill those NaNs with some value) and sum the added column.

```
df['count'] = 1
df_grouped = df[['boxCode', 'bla', 'version', 'count']].groupby(by=['boxCode', 'bla', 'version'], as_index=False).sum()
```

Comment: Thanks John Redford. This works pretty well but is there a way I can also count the rows with NaN? Or perhaps I should instead be creating default values rather than NaN  in my dataframes for this to work?

Edit: Solution provided by Seiji Armstrong accomplishes this.

Comment: It would better if you could elaborate on your answer, so that when someone in the feature with a similar problem can understand the answer.